# springboot Can not deserialize-HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to read json in my spring boot project.

My JSON data is as follows:

```
[{
    "userId":"101"
},
{
    "partNum":"aaa"
},
{
    "partNum":"bbb"
},
{
    "partNum":"ccc"
}]
```

I have created a DTO class:

```
public class TcPartDto {
    private String userId;
    private List<String> partNum;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public List<String> getPartNum() {
        return partNum;
    }
}
```

And I am calling it in my Controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/volumeinfo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public List<TcPartVolumeDto> volumeinfo(@RequestBody TcPartDto partList) throws Exception {
    return tcService.fetchVolumeInfo(partList);
}
```

But I get the following error:

Through **Postman** I get this error:

> "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   tc.service.model.TcPartDto out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@5359141a; line: 1, column: 1]; nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of tc.service.model.TcPartDto out of
>   START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5359141a;
>   line: 1, column: 1]"

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTO you've created does not match the json data it's trying to read.

Based on your DTO sample json should be:

```
{
  "userId" : "someId",
  "partNum" : [ "partNum1", "partNum2"]
}
```

otherwise if json object you're consuming is fixed then DTO should be:

```
public class MyDTO {

    private String userId;
    private String partNum;

    // ...
}
```

and with your controller with a parameter of type

```
List<MyDTO>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a JSON Array to your `public List<TcPartVolumeDto> volumeinfo(@RequestBody TcPartDto partList)` method. But it should be deserialize to a single object: `TcPartDto partList`.

Change your JSON structure to send only a single `TcPartDto` or make sure your that your `volumeinfo` method can receive an `Array` or `List`.

And you have to change your JSON structure in case you want to send a single object:

```
{
  "userId": 101,
  "partNum": [
    "aaa",
    "bbb",
    "ccc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't change the JSON format like that, its generated from another application and I have to use it as is

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out various answers.

if in case this is the json that you want to map without changing the class :

JSON:

```
[{
    "userId":"101"
},
{
    "partNum":"aaa"
},
{
    "partNum":"bbb"
},
{
    "partNum":"ccc"
}]
```

Class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class TcPartDto {

    private String userId;
    private List<String> partNum;
//getters and setters 
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/volumeinfo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public List<TcPartVolumeDto> volumeinfo(@RequestBody TcPartDto[] partArray) throws Exception {
    return tcService.fetchVolumeInfo(partArray);
}
```

Output:

```
[{"userId":"101","partNum":null},{"userId":null,"partNum":["aaa"]},{"userId":null,"partNum":["bbb"]},{"userId":null,"partNum":["ccc"]}]
```